# VF Component modifying an apex:variable outside of its scope

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, apex-variable

I just stumbled upon a weird behavior of Visualforce Components (or `apex:variables`). Please see the code below and then the end result:

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:variable var="foo" value="{!0}" />

    * Before : {!foo}

    <br/>

    * CMP : <c:varTestCmp input="1"></c:varTestCmp>

    <br/>

    * After : {!foo}
</apex:page>
```

**VF Component**

```
<apex:component layout="none">
    <apex:attribute name="input" type="Integer"/>
    <apex:variable var="foo" value="{!input + 1}" />

    {!foo}

</apex:component>
```

The end result is the following:

[image]

It seems that the VF Component and the VF Page are sharing the variables, and the change in VF Component is affecting the variable that is defined outside of it, in VF page.

Now, if I rename the variable inside the component to `foo2`, I get the *expected* output:

[image]

I haven't used `<apex:variable>` often, so this caught me by surprise. I was expecting that a variable defined within a component would only be modified within that component.

This could be an issue if someone decides to create a library of reusable components, because, as far as I've seen, even when a component is within another component, and they have a variable with a same name, they will be affecting each other.

Other than naming the variables differently, what other options do we have to isolate them within a containing component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apex:variable` variables always have a global scope. You necessarily need use different variable names in all components and/or pages (e.g. via `apex:include`). Rarely, it happens that this behavior is desirable if you want to communicate across components, but mostly it is just a hassle. You should avoid using `apex:variable` for any real work, and instead use wrapper classes and/or attributes, as appropriate, and use Apex Code to manipulate the data.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the explanation. I'll avoid them in the future.